# is my ethernet cable color placement wrong?

Tags: networking, ethernet, colors, cable

so i have my internet from my neighbor for free (thank you kind neighbor :D )... he changed the cable with new one yesterday but i needed another cable for another computer so i did it myself... so i used the same exact color placement he used and internet works fine... but what i noticed is that color placement was nothing like i saw on internet when i searched... the colors are white orange/orange/white blue/blue/white green/green/white brown/brown so is it wrong or is it fine? internet works but is it working worse if colors are wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about?  It *sounds like* you're asking about the order of the individual wires in a Cat 5 cable, but as written your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong. It'll have signal integrity problems unless pins 4&5 are a twisted pair, and pins 3&6 are a twisted pair.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  While there are potential issues for traffic interference between the pairs, if you're not having any issues then it's not really an issue.  If you were in a large building with massive amounts of cables and needed the most speed from each cable, then yes it would probably be an issue.

LAN cables are meant to be "straight through" meaning that each wire must be on the same pin on one side as it is the other.  The reason they have a specific pattern is due to the way that the cables are twisted together to reduce cross-talk traffic between the wires.  This is something only really noticeable when you require the fastest possible traffic or have large amounts of other LAN cables nearby.  Since your internet is working for you, there is no need to worry about the order of the wires.

Comment: i won't have more than 2 computers connected and it works... but i am interested if it will work better if they were    in right order... and thank you for the answer btw :)

Comment: If it's just for your internet and you're not heavily streaming videos, file sharing, or gaming, then you won't notice a difference at all.  The standards that you were looking at earlier were designed for large datacenters and businesses that need to bleed as much power from the lines as possible.